# react boolean attribute not working, video not autoplaying

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a react `<video>` component. And I have added autoplay as an attribute.

```
<video autoplay muted src="/vids/vid.mp4">
```

And not working. But when I set `autoplay="true"` it starts working.

```
<video autoplay="true" muted src="/vids/vid.mp4">  //Works
```

why is it for a boolean attribute, only putting `autoplay` is not working on react? on other occasions for attributes like `hidden` it works.

Why is this happening? Which one is the correct way to specify boolean attribute?

Comment: autoplay={true} works for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem with the `autoplay` attribute with React. You want to use `autoPlay` instead. You should then just be able to use it like this:

```
<video autoPlay muted src="/vids/vid.mp4">
```